# Warped Motherboard, dead NIC

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter

Well, I did something stupid. Last March I rebuilt my computer.  For some reason or another one of the mounting screws was not set properly, resulting in the top of the board bending at an angle (maybe 10-15 degrees).  I told myself I'd fix it the next day....which of course I never did.  Then I just flat out forgot about it.  Last night my on board NIC died.  I think the warped board could have been a factor.  Now I am wondering if I should just replace the NIC (and fix the board mounting) or replace the board all together (who knows what else could have been damaged).  So far I am leaning for the later.  So I am wondering, would replacing the board just be overly paranoid?  These things aren't exactly cheap.  Thoughts?

Comment: I say you just replace the baord.  10-15 degrees is significant....